# CSS issue With <ul> tag in Firefox

Tags: css, html-lists

The following layout renders properly in Chrome, Safari, IE & Opera.  In Firefox, the breaks are ignored.

This is the expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

My preference is a CSS tweak that will get it working in FF (and keep it working in the others), but I'll take another approach to achieve the same results, if necessary.

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mNmn/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }

  ul li {
    clear: both;
  }

  ul li * {
    float: left;
  }

  ul li div:first-child {
    width: 100px;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
  <li><div>One</div><div>A</div></li>
  <li><div>Two</div><div>B</div></li>
  <li><div>Three</div><div>C</div></li>
  <li><div>Four</div><div>D - 1<br>D - 2<br>D - 3<br>D - 4</div></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
br { float:none !important; }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mNmn/1/)

Or use a more specific rule instead of `ul li *` to not apply float to the `br`s.

Tested on Nightly 21 and Canary 26. `float` seems to affect `br` elements only in Firefox nevertheless.

Comment: No problem. `=]` Normally, a person would expect `<br>` to insert a line break nevertheless of CSS styling.